# Is there an advantage to using json.dumps vs pandas.to_json to convert a pyspark dataframe to a json string?

Tags: python, json, pandas, pyspark

I would like to convert a simple pyspark dataframe into a json string in python. It looks like I have a couple of options for this. For example, if I have a dataframe of People:

```
+----+----------+
|name|       dob|
+----+----------+
| Mia|1980-01-31|
|Jose|1967-05-15|
|Carl|1995-11-25|
+----+----------+
```

I could use either

`json.dumps(my_people.rdd.map(lambda row: row.asDict()).collect())`

OR

`my_people.toPandas().to_json(orient='records')`

to get what seems like effectively the same results (with some variations in spacing. For example: `'[{"name": "Mia", "dob": "1980-01-31"}, {"name": "Jose", "dob": "1967-05-15"}, {"name": "Carl", "dob": "1995-11-25"}]'`.

Given this, is there a strong reason to prefer one or the other? Why or why not?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use :

```py
df.write.json()
```

In theory, you are not supposed to process your data with spark and then collect them in python ... of course, you can do it, nobody will stop you but the amount of data processed in parallele with spark should not be able to fit your driver's memory.

If you still want to do it, then simply :

```py
df.toJSON().collect()
```

Here, applied to your sample data:

```
['{"name":"Mia","dob":"1980-01-31"}',
 '{"name":"Jose","dob":"1967-05-15"}',
 '{"name":"Carl","dob":"1995-11-25"}']
```

Comment: Ah! The idea is to perform the query using pyspark and then post the results as json data to an API. `df.toJSON().collect()` doesn't seem to quite work as it produces a list of stringified objects like this: ['{}', '{}']. Great note about the memory usage though!

Comment: @mshell_lauren Not sure to understand your point. I applied the function to your sample data in my EDIT. Can you be more precise ?

Comment: Sure thing @Steven!, so, what df.toJSON().collect() returns is a list of stringified json objects. What I'm looking for is a stringified list of objects. While the former returns a json representation per row, the latter is a json representation of the collection. In the end, I really wanted to know if there was any performance issues around using an rdd vs pandas to build this.